# Merge database statistics into google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, statistics, logging

A couple of sites I administer have this situation:

- Google Analytics is set up for regular traffic reporting
- I have some sort of cron tab emailing/logging weekly/monthly statistics like number of new users, number of users entered a contest, number of new password requests sent, and so forth

Is there a way to track those rather customized backend statistics in a way I can view them in Google Analytics alongside regular reportings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, although it will require some coding. With PHP you can utilize the PHP-GA library and send the data directly from the server.

http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/

An example of how to utilize this:
[Turn Google Analytics into an inventory profiling system](http://techpad.co.uk/content.php?sid=209)

The article is about how to store inventory levels in Google Analytics, but it can be adapted for whatever stats you want, like total signups, contest data, etc.

Comment: Great answer. The example is spot on. The only thing I wonder about is, if it is possible to somehow track both types in the same analytics profile. For example, I would be interested, if increased visits or visit durations is reflected in new weekly users registration data. Then again, I suppose one could also implement the php side to send single events for each register, to get even more detail woven in.